# Installing Windows without C drive

Tags: windows

I cannot change C drive letter from disk management. I have installed Win10 OS in 2 partitions C and D drive, when i boot from D drive it becomes C. I want to remove C drive from my computer to test my application. How should i change the boot partition?

Thanks.